# Help identifying component in SMPS

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, identification, feedback

I have been working on a Schroff/Cherokee Europe PE1947/23B SMPS (circa 2004?) and have had trouble identifying a component within the circuit.

This SMPS features the following outputs:

- +12v DC @ 8A
- -12v DC @ 4A
- +5v DC @ 36A

All of the outputs appear to be generated from a central transformer with a winding for each output. From the way it is structured, it appears that each output is electrically isolated from all other outputs.

Across the output windings of the transformer are a small brown component, shown below, that I cannot identify. The component has six leads (three per side) and a metal cover along the top of the component, under which appears to be ferrite material.
[image: Top view]
[image: Side view 1]
[image: Side view 2]

In the circuit, the two larger leads (which pass through to the top of the device) are connected <strike>across the transformer winding for the applicable rail</strike> *to a rather esoteric control circuit*. Note that these winding voltages are much higher the final output voltage (around 55v and 120v AC for the 5 and 12v rails, respectively). These then look like they are fed through a rectifier and then a buck circuit.

Within the circuit, the smaller leads are bridged to the adjacent lead (as shown in the image below), and each of these feeds to <strike>a rather esoteric control circuit</strike> *the output transformer secondary winding for the associated output*.[image: connections]

I have removed one of these components from the circuit, and found that the two smaller leads on one side are not connected to each other, but they are connected to the corresponding lead on the opposite side of the device. Resistance between the two larger leads is approximately **one ohm**, and looks like it feeds a coil inside the device.

The resistance seems too low to be a relay. I note that the +12v and -12v rails have this (component), but the +5v rail does not (possibly due to its higher current rating).

This leaves me with the following questions:

- Where can I find a datasheet for this device?
- What is the likely purpose of this device in the circuit (I'm thinking some kind of current sensing)?

**Update 1 (clarification):**

In the image below, the black circles are the terminals of the device. The yellow text shows the resistances between various terminals (measured at DC with a digital multimeter). The green areas show how the terminals are connected on the PCB.

[image: connections]

**Update 2 (more clarification):**

Below is the control daughterboard mentioned in the comments. This appears to be shared between a few different Cherokee Europe power supplies. These supplies were also made by or for Phillips, and appear in various telecommunications oriented power supplies, as well as the Phillips Allura nuclear gamma camera.
[image: control pcb daughter]

This is the control PCB in circuit. The ribbon cable at the bottom of the image is connected to each of the three output rails. Under the heatsink near the top left corner is an LM340T15, which is fed from a 20v transformer tap via a half-wave rectifier. The two power transistors near the centre right of the image are both BD132 PNP transistors.
[image: control pcb in circuit]

Comment: May be a noise filter. Could be coupled L's or L's and C's.

Comment: What is the resistance measurement between each of the smaller leads (from one side of the device to the other), and what do they connect to in the control circuit?

Comment: @BruceAbbott I have updated my original post with an extra diagram that should hopefully clarify this.

Comment: That's what I suspected. It appears to be a step-down transformer with two single-turn secondary windings, perhaps used to power the control circuit? Need to know more about the control circuit to be sure.

Comment: @BruceAbbott I'm afraid the control circuit is a bit of a black box to me, thus the confusion. It consists of a daughterboard with some passive components around it. Googling the daughter board suggests it is an identical daughter board used in many different supplies.

This is a situation where I'd love a schematic, but have had no luck in finding any.

Comment: Anything you can share could be useful. Which other power supplies use this daughterboard? Can you show us a photo of it? And why do you need to know what this brown component is?

Comment: @BruceAbbott I have edited the OP to add some photos and details of the daughterboard. I am chasing these brown components as they are the only components I have been unable to identify in the circuit. Diagnosis of this SMPS fault so far suggests an issue in the feedback/control circuit, however swapping this daughter card from a working unit has not resolved the issue, and testing the capacitors around the control circuit out-of-circuit with an ESR meter yields expected values. Application wise - these supplies are generally used in telecommunications systems.

Comment: From the appearance alone it looks like it might be a current transformer or some other sort of current transducer, but if that's the case the the way it's being used in the circuit makes no sense whatsoever, so I have to conclude that it isn't being used for that. Bruce's idea that it might be to power the control circuit seems reasonable, or it could be a transformer plus signal conditioning to provide an input signal to the control board as part of the feedback.

Comment: When the PSU is powered on, what sort of signal do you get across the smaller leads? If it's a transformer I would assume some kind of sinusoid at a low (relative to the big leads) voltage. Knowing exactly what that voltage is would help to determine if it's being used to measure something or to power something.

Comment: I would second @Hearth in saying it is a current transformer of some sort.  The parallel wire links form two half turns through the core that can be series or parallel (in this case) connected.

Comment: @KalleMP I don't think it's a current transformer, since the asker states that it's connected directly across the transformer windings. It's probably a measurement device, but a current transformer would be connected in series, not parallel. I suppose it could be a current transformer being used for entirely the wrong purpose, but that seems a little far-fetched.

Comment: I've had a closer look at this and realised I made a mistake. The smaller sets of leads go to the transformer windings, not the larger ones.

I suspect that @Hearth may be correct in that this could be a current monitoring solution. This same component is seen in the control circuitry for the other outputs, although the 5v rail has what appears to be a transformer with tens of turns on one winding, and a single winding on the other (possibly due to its much higher current rating).

I have corrected connections in my OP.

Comment: I'm looking at this thing now and I'm increasingly thinking it is a current monitor. I suspect (but have not confirmed) that the wires form the larger leads form a coil around the smaller leads that pass from one side to the other. This would also explain the ferrite around the outside (under the silver cover).

Comment: @toxicantidote A current transformer would typically have the lower-resistance winding carry the sensed current, with the higher-resistance (i.e. more turns) winding being the output. They don't coil around each other; a current transformer is just an ordinary transformer, really, with an extremely high turns ratio.